# When in AC: Syndicate does the song "Underground" play?

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

Ubisoft recently posted the entire soundtrack of Assassin's Creed: Syndicate on their Youtube channel, UBILOUD. I've listened to the tracks and would like to know the context in which the track [Underground](https://youtu.be/F8p1hor857E) which I like quite a lot, is being played.

I am perfectly okay with answers containing spoilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked some youtube videos, and it appears to play during the credits.

calls it the Ending Song.

Note: I'm not 100% sure about this, but the evidence points to it. Youtube commenters are referring to an emotional scene that played around the time of this song, and searching for the keywords of that scene returns the ending of the game.

---

Update: I finished the game. This song does not exactly play during the credits, but it does play at the very end of the main storyline,  during the emotional moment I mentioned above. I will not spoil it any further because this moment has significance to people who played earlier installments.

Answer (score -2):

Modern day scene at the very end when Rebecca and Shane are ambushed in the crypt

Comment: First off: it is Shaun,  not Shane. Secondly,  it is not a crypt, it is a vault. Thirdly, Shaun and Rebecca are the ones doing the ambushing.